# Find number of arrays with XOR sum equals to zero

Tags: algorithm

How to determine number of arrays of length N such that it satisfies below two conditions:

1. Each Value of array is between 0-5 inclusively.
2. XOR sum of all value of the array is 0.

**Example**: Let *N* = 2

*then total arrays with XOR sum zero = 6*

*which are-
(0, 0)
(1, 1)
(2, 2)
(3, 3)
(4, 4)
(5, 5)*

So how to find out this in a efficient way?

Comment: 6^{n-1}. N-1 degrees of freedom. If n-1 elements are given, no choice for the last element

Comment: @Damien not really, what if `N` is 4, `a[:3]` is `[1, 2, 4]`, so last element should be 7, but 7 is prohibited.

Comment: @Damien if N=3, there will be total of 28 possible arrays whose XOR sum is 0.

Comment: @Shubh Effectively, I missed that. I think anyway that a rather simple formula should exist. One possibily is to calculate the answer for several small values of N and then deduce the formula

Answer (score 4):

That could be done in *O(N)* using [dynamic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming#Examples:_Computer_algorithms).

Let's say `dp[i][j]` is a number of arrays such that they have `i` elements and their XOR-sum is `j`.

Note that `0 <= j <= 7`, because if `N == 6` array `[1, 2, 4, 4, 2, 1]` matches, but it's prefix `[1, 2, 4]` has XOR-sum 7. Also you can't get XOR-sum more than 7 because all the numbers in range 0 to 5 can't have any other terms than 2^2, 2^1 and 2^0 when decomposed into powers of 2.

Here's the formula to calculate `dp[i][j]` using previously calculated values:

```
dp[i][j] = 0
# k is XOR-sum of previously calculated number of arrays of length i-1.
for k in range(0, 8):
    # x is a number we append to arrays of length i-1 so XOR-sum is j.
    x = j xor k
    if x <= 5:
        dp[i][j] += d[i - 1][k]
```

And that's the rest of code:

```
# Assume there's a two dimensional array of integers dp of size N+1 x 8.

# Dynamics initialization.
# There's only one possible array of length 0: []. It's XOR-sum is 0.
dp[0][0] = 1 
for i in range(1, 8):
    dp[0][i] = 0

# Dynamics state calculation.
for i in range(1, N+1):
    for j in range(0, 8):
        # Here comes code from above.
        dp[i][j] = 0
        for k in range(0, 8):
            x = j xor k
            if x <= 5:
                dp[i][j] += d[i - 1][k]

# Answer is dp[N][0].
print(dp[N][0])
```

Dynamics state calculation makes *N*8*8* iterations, so complexity is *O(N)* (note that despite the linear complexity, the constant 64 might be quite large).

There is a way to make this be calculated in *O(log N)* using [matrix binary exponentiation](https://cp-algorithms.com/algebra/binary-exp.html). Briefly: you need to calculate a 8x8 matrix `M`
telling how `dp[i-1][*]` values turn to `dp[i][*]` values; then calculate `dp[0] * M^N`, where `dp[0]` is `[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]` (exactly as in dynamics initialization).

Comment: can you explain the recursion a little bit can't really understand it well.

Comment: @WasimAhmad that's not a recursion, I'll add pseudocode how to use it and more details

Comment: @By recursion I meant the relationship dp[i][j] = sum dp[i-1][k]. This is a recursive relationship which you are calculating using a table. The same be done using recursion or recursion + memorization.